# Changing Default Action dynamically in Routing - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is how i designed the **RegisterRoutes** function. and based on  the condition am selecting the Action for **HomeController**. So far so Good.

```
string env = "Index";
if (some condition from config)
{
    env = "Test";
}
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                             
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
    new { controller = "Home", action = env, id = "" }  
);
```

Problem starts here when am reirecting to other controller by default if dont specify an action(for eg: am calling SampleController) the "env"(Which was set in RegisterRoutes is called. **if env is set as "Index" Index action is called, if env is set "Test" Test action is called  in all other controllers as well.**

My intention is only for HomeController this condition should be set and for all other controller i want Index to be the default action.

How do i make this work ? is it possible to dynamically  change the action for all other controllers ? Is there a better way i can do this.

Share your suggestions

Thanks

Comment: You could make one specific route for `"Home/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = env }` and the default route `"{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks! I tried but always the default route is getting called ?

Comment: Did you put `"Home/{action}/{id}"` first? (the order is important)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should do this in your routing engine. I would route everything in code and call the correct action from in there. For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    switch(config) 
    {
        case "OtherAction":
            return OtherAction();

        case "AnotherAction":
            return AnotherAction();

        case "Index":
            break;

        default:
            //Er, how did we get here?
            throw new HttpNotFoundException();
    }

    //Normal index action continues here...

}

public ActionResult OtherAction() { ... }
public ActionResult AnotherAction() { ... }
```